# RegEx for matching special patterns

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm trying to match a String like this:`62.00|LQ+2*2,FP,MD*3 "Description"`
Where the decimal value is 2 digits optional, each user is characterized by two Chars and it can be followed by

> (\+[\d]+)? or (\*[\d]+)? or none, or both, or both in different order

like:

> LQ*2+4 | LQ+4*2 | LQ*2 | LQ+8 | LQ

Description is also optional

What i have tried is this:

```
Pattern.compile("^(?<number>[\\d]+(\\.[\\d]{2})?)\\|(?<users>([A-Z]{2}){1}(((\\+[\\d]+)?(\\*[\\d]+)?)|((\\+[\\d]+)?(\\*[\\d]+)?))((,[A-Z]{2})(((\\+[\\d]+)?(\\*[\\d]+)?)|((\\+[\\d]+)?(\\*[\\d]+)?)))*)(\\s\\\"(?<message>.+)\\\")?$");
```

I need to get all the users so i can split them by ',' and then further regex my way into it.But i cannot grab anything out of it.The desired output from

> 62.00|LQ+2*2,FP,MD*3 "Description"

Should be:

> 62.00
>
> LQ+2*2,FP,MD*3
>
> Description

Accepted inputs should be of these kind:

> 62.00|LQ+2*2,FP,MD*3
>
> 30|LQ "Burgers"
>
> 35.15|LQ*2,FP+2*4,MD*3+4 "Potatoes"
>
> 35.15|LQ,FP,MD

Comment: Could you provide a couple of concrete example strings and what the expected output should be? It's not really easy to understand what you're asking

Comment: @Misantorp I edited it..

Comment: Why not split `62.00|LQ+2*2,FP,MD*3 "Description"` on `|`? This would give you `62.00` and `LQ+2*2,FP,MD*3 "Description"` so you already have `number` part. Then split second part on *one (first)* space into two parts (via `split(" ", 2)` to get `LQ+2*2,FP,MD*3` `"Description"`, this way even if description has more spaces it will be in one string. Then split `LQ+2*2,FP,MD*3` on comma to get each player.

Comment: @Pshemo Because I don't know if the user is going to put a number or something else at it's place..

Comment: I was under impression that your regex was only for *separating* valid string into parts which would be accessed later via named groups. But now you mention that your string can contain also other data which are incorrect. Could you add that information to your question, possibly with example?

Comment: I updated it with some inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precise regex to match the inputs you described should be fulfilled by this regex,

```
^(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)\|([a-zA-Z]{2}(?:(?:\+\d+(?:\*\d+)?)|(?:\*\d+(?:\+\d+)?))?(?:,[a-zA-Z]{2}(?:(?:\+\d+(?:\*\d+)?)|(?:\*\d+(?:\+\d+)?))?)*)(?: +(.+))?$
```

Where group1 will contain the number that can have optional decimals upto two digits and group2 will have the comma separated inputs as you described in your post and group3 will contain the optional description if present.

**Explanation of regex:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)` - Matches the number which can have optional 2 digits after decimal and captures it in group1
- `\|` - Matches literal `|` present in your input after the number
- `([a-zA-Z]{2}(?:(?:\+\d+(?:\*\d+)?)|(?:\*\d+(?:\+\d+)?))?(?:,[a-zA-Z]{2}(?:(?:\+\d+(?:\*\d+)?)|(?:\*\d+(?:\+\d+)?))?)*)` - This part matches two letters followed by any combination of `+` followed by number and optionally having `*` followed by number OR `*` followed by number and optionally having `+` followed by number exactly either once or whole of it being optional and captures it in group2
- `(?: +(.+))?` - This matches the optional description and captures it in group3
- `$` - Marks end of input

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aGkePD/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that we have several optional groups here, that might not be a problem. The problem I'm having is that I'm not quite sure what would be the range of our inputs and what might be desired outputs.

---

### RegEx 1

If we are just matching everything, that I'm guessing, we might like to start with something similar to:

```
[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?\|[A-Z]{2}[+*]?([0-9]+)?[+*]?([0-9]+)?,[A-Z]{2},[A-Z]{2}[+*]?([0-9]+)?(\s+"Description")?
```

Here, we simply add a `?` after every sub-expression that we wish to have it optional, then we use char lists and quantifiers, and start swiping everything from left to right, to cover all inputs.

If we like to capture, then we simply wrap any part that we want captured with a capturing group `()`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BVrZvR/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]{2})?\\|[A-Z]{2}[+*]?([0-9]+)?[+*]?([0-9]+)?,[A-Z]{2},[A-Z]{2}[+*]?([0-9]+)?(\\s+\"Description\")?";
final String string = "62.00|LQ+2*2,FP,MD*3 \"Description\"\n"
     + "62|LQ+2*2,FP,MD*3 \"Description\"\n"
     + "62|LQ+2*2,FP,MD*3\n"
     + "62|LQ*2,FP,MD*3\n"
     + "62|LQ+8,FP,MD*3\n"
     + "62|LQ,FP,MD";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

---

### RegEx 2

If we wish to output three groups that is listed:

```
([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)\|([A-Z]{2}[+*]?([0-9]+)?[+*]?([0-9]+)?,[A-Z]{2},[A-Z]{2}[+*]?([0-9]+)?)(\s+"Description")?
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/IZXW7j/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "([0-9]+(\\.[0-9]{2})?)\\|([A-Z]{2}[+*]?([0-9]+)?[+*]?([0-9]+)?,[A-Z]{2},[A-Z]{2}[+*]?([0-9]+)?)(\\s+\"Description\")?";
final String string = "62.00|LQ+2*2,FP,MD*3 \"Description\"\n"
     + "62|LQ+2*2,FP,MD*3 \"Description\"\n"
     + "62|LQ+2*2,FP,MD*3\n"
     + "62|LQ*2,FP,MD*3\n"
     + "62|LQ+8,FP,MD*3\n"
     + "62|LQ,FP,MD";
final String subst = "\\1\\n\\3\\n\\7";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

#### RegEx 3

Based on updated desired output, this might work:

```
([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)\|((?:[A-Z]{2}[+*]?([0-9]+)?[+*]?([0-9]+)?,?)(?:[A-Z]{2}[+*]?([0-9]+)?[*+]?([0-9]+)?,?[A-Z]{2}?[*+]?([0-9]+)?[+*]?([0-9]+)?)?)(\s+"(.+?)")?
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/VG0mku/1/)

Comment: I'm going to test this now, but what i need to avoid is having LQ+2+2, so two same quantifiers in a user like LQ+2+4,  LQ*2*7 or more than two quantifiers like LQ*2+3+7*8

Comment: I'll write the cases I want it to match because it would be easier

Comment: i updated it, also thank you for the help :) I've been struggling with this for a while now https://regex101.com/r/IZXW7j/3/

Comment: Pushpesh's solved it. Thank you too for your help :)